# Python Selenium - Unable to press Instagram DM button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, instagram

I'm currently in the making of a Python Selenium Instagram bot but have just ran into a simple but silly problem. I'm wondering why exactly this line of code won't execute it's purpose, which is to press the Instagram DM button button that pops up after you just logged into Instagram. I'm also searching for a option that actually executes it's purpose, hopefully a xpath option.

```
go_to_dm = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "/html/body/div[1]/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/a/svg")
go_to_dm.click()
```

For those interested, here's the full code, everything works correctly except the last line.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

username = ""
password = ""

ChromePath = (r"C:\Users\04fean90\OneDrive - Kungsbacka kommun\Dokument\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromePath)

driver.get("https://instagram.com/accounts/login")

sleep(1)

cookie_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Accept All']")
cookie_button.click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div/div[1]/div/form/div/div[1]/div/label/input").send_keys(username)

driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div/div[1]/div/form/div/div[2]/div/label/input").send_keys(password)

sleep(5)

login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']")
login_button.click()

sleep(10)

# not now
save_login_info_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div/div/div/button")
save_login_info_button.click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Not Now')]").click()

sleep(10)

go_to_dm = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "/html/body/div[1]/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/a/svg")
go_to_dm.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do the trick.

```
go_to_dm = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@aria-label='Direct']")
go_to_dm.click()
```

Also, I see you have a lot of absolute xpaths. It is not a good practice. Try to use relative xpaths instead of absolute ones. They are easy on maintenance, readability, and execution per se.